# Jsoup cant extract stock price from the webpage

Tags: java, jsoup

I have been using Jsoup to extract a a stock price from a stock trading website. The stock price is updated automatically at regular intervals. I have tried using the examples given in the cookbook,,but have not been having any luck please help me out...

The following is what i have tried...

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class sup {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url="http://money.rediff.com/companies/selan-exploratio/17020281";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        String quote = doc.select("#ltpid .f22 span").first().text();
        System.out.println(quote);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock price seems to be stored in a span having the ID `ltpid`. Using the `#ltpid` selector is thus sufficient. Your selector tries to find a span which has an ancestor with the class `.f22` which has an ancestor with the ID `ltpid`.

Read http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html for explanations about selectors.

EDIT:

You have a second problem though: this span is not inside the document you have loaded. It's inside an iframe which has the following URL: http://money.rediff.com/money1/current_stat.php?companyCode=17020281.

Try with this URL instead of the one you're using, and it'll work.

Comment: I tried using only `#ltpid` but i get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Using FireBug, it's easy to find the location in the DOM of a specific part of a page, to move up in the ancestors, to find that it's contained inside an iframe, and to see that the iframe has the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://money.rediff.com/companies/selan-exploratio/17020281").get();
        String javaScript = doc.select(".m_sectionright script").first().toString();
        String regStr = "iValue\\s*=\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d*";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regStr);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(javaScript);
        while (matcher.find()) {
              System.out.println(matcher.group().replace("iValue = ",""));
              break;
        }
    }
```

The easiest way is to get it from the javascript block.